# Merging duplicate arrays with count

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.1, array-merge

I'm working with large sets of data and i need to merge the arrays when they are duplicate. If they get merged I need a count added to the array.

```
array:3721 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "gmail.com."
    "code" => 554
    "status" => 50
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "apied.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "beton-dobbelaere.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 50
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "live.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "hotmail.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 50
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 55
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
  ]
```

This should look something like:

```
array:3721 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "gmail.com."
    "code" => 554
    "status" => 50
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "apied.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "beton-dobbelaere.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 50
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "live.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "hotmail.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 50
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 55
    "amount" => 1
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "subscriber" => "telenet.be"
    "code" => 550
    "status" => 51
    "amount" => 2
  ]
```

When I merged this example using

```
array_unique($hardbounces, SORT_REGULAR);
```

I was left with around 534 results instead of  3721 this is great, only I need to know the amount as well and it has to be somewhat efficient because the result sets can be very big (much bigger).

After it need to be sorted as well to domains and amounts.

I'm using laravel 5.1 if necessary I could turn the array into a collection so helper functions are available

Comment: interesting question. did you try `array_count_values()` ?

Comment: Are you currently collecting these datasets from something like MySql?

Comment: Yes get these values with eloquent.

Comment: why don't you use then aggregate SQL functions to count?

Comment: I'm not very good at subqueries and all that stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself with a foreach loop it runs faster then i expected (0.3179 seconds)

```
   $merged = [];
    foreach($hardbounces as &$hardbounce){
        if(empty($merged)){
            $merged[] = $hardbounce;
        }else{
            $i = 0;
            foreach($merged as $key => $merge){
                $i++;
                if($hardbounce['subscriber'] == $merge['subscriber'] && $hardbounce['code'] == $merge['code'] && $hardbounce['status'] == $merge['status']){
                    $merged[$key]['amount']++;
                    break;
                }
                if(count($merged) == $i){
                    $merged[] = $hardbounce;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I loop through the bounces, if merged is empty (first iteration) it just adds the hardbounce.
From that point on I will loop through the new array and check if there is a duplicate. When this happens we just add one to the amount and break out of the foreach. Otherwise it will eventually still add duplicates.
After i check if we made it to the last iteration, which means if it still hasn't break-ed we should add the hardbounce because it doesn't exist yet.

To be clear I made sure the amount 1 already exists before this loop runs, instead of adding it during this loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient this code is with really many items (BTW, you did not mention the order of magnitude of the numbers) , but I think it will be more efficient than converting arrays into Laravel collections

```
$arr = [
      0 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "gmail.com.",
        "code" => 554,
        "status" => 50,
      ],
      1 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "apied.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51,
      ],
      2 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "beton-dobbelaere.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 50,
      ],
      3 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "live.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51,
      ],
      4 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "hotmail.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51,
      ],
      5 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 50,
      ],
      6 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 55,
      ],
      7 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51,
      ],
      8 =>  [
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51,
      ],
];

$res = [];
foreach($arr as $element) {
    if(empty($res[$element['subscriber']])) {
        $res[$element['subscriber']] = [$element, 'count' => 1];
    } else {
        $res[$element['subscriber']]['count']++;
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: This still gives me 3721 results.

Comment: it would be hard to debug unless I have the full dataset somehow. Do you see how it works on the sample you provided?

Comment: Yes i do, i just ran it with just the 8 results. This stil isn't what it should look like tho. It sets the domain name as a key which is unnecessary in my opinion and inside that array it added another array for the count which should just be a key with a value.

Comment: I did manage to solve it myself, take a look at the answer i presented

Comment: I see what your doing why your adding the domains as keys, to see if it already exists of course, this still doesn't mean its unique. status & code should also be taken in account.

I should have provided my case better. Sorry

Comment: ok, I see now. But you managed to solve it yourself with just a custom code and I believe it's better and relatively efficient than using Laravel collection. However, what I meant in my comment about SQL aggregate functions, it's not about subqueries. All you have to do is `SELECT subscriber,COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY subscriber, status, code`

Comment: Yeah but it's not that simple. it should have 1 amount for each result. Each result that is identical to another should not be added and 1 should be added to the amount of its twin.

And im just using arrays, yes when I retrieve data with eloquent I get it in an collection. when I format it I save it in an array I just meant that if somebody had a good efficient solution that used a laravel collection function i could format it into an collection.

Im quite sure you can do this with just SQL because this is very powerfull, It's just not a very easy solution for me personally.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    $input = array(
      0 => array(
        "subscriber" => "gmail.com.",
        "code" => 554,
        "status" => 50),
      1 => array(
        "subscriber" => "apied.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51),
      2 => array(
        "subscriber" => "beton-dobbelaere.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 50),
      3 => array(
        "subscriber" => "live.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51),
      4 => array(
        "subscriber" => "hotmail.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51),
      5 => array(
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 50),
      6 => array(
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 55),
      7 => array(
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51),
      8 => array(
        "subscriber" => "telenet.be",
        "code" => 550,
        "status" => 51)
    );


    /**
     *@param array $counted The array already counted or NULL
     *@param array $new The array to count or to merge with the counted $counted
     */
    function merge_xor_count(array $counted = NULL, array $new){
        if($counted === NULL){
            $counted = array();
        }
        foreach($new as $keyNew => $valueNew){
            $matches = false;
            foreach($counted as $keyOut => $valueOut){
                if ($valueOut['subscriber'] == $valueNew['subscriber'] && $valueOut['code'] == $valueNew['code'] &&
                    $valueOut['status'] == $valueNew['status']){
                    $matches = $keyOut;
                }
            }
            if($matches !== false){
                $counted[$matches]['amount']++;
            }
            else{
                if(!isset($valueNew['amount'])) $valueNew['amount'] = 1;
                $counted[] = $valueNew;
            }
        }
        return $counted;
    }

    $output = merge_xor_count(NULL, $input);

    print_r ($output)."\n";

    $output = merge_xor_count($output, $input);

    print_r ($output)."\n";


    ?>
```

Comment: This still outputs the full result set? Still get 3721 results, Take a look at the answer i provided myself.